# the differentiability from an oscillation estimate

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

If we have an oscillation estimate of $u\in W^{2,n} (B^{+}) \cap C^0(\bar B^{+})$, and $u=0$ on $T = B \cap \partial R^{n}_{+}$, that
$$osc_{B^{+}} \frac{u}{x_{n}} \leq C.$$
Then how comes that $u$ is differential on $T$ ? Here $B = B_{1}(0)$.

This is a question I met when reading the remark of Theorem 9.31 in the book "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order" by Gilbarg and Trudinger, version of revision of the 1983 second edition(P254).

Answer (score 1):

The theorem does not have just $C$ on the right: it has $CR^\alpha$, where $R$ is the radius of the ball.  This
implies $$u(x',x_n) = f(y')\,x_n + O((|x_n|+|x'-y'|)^{1+\alpha}),\qquad (x',x_n)\to (y',0)  \tag{1}$$ where $f(y')$ is the limit of $u(x',x_n)/x_n$ as $(x',x_n)\to (y',0)$.  From (1) it also follows that 
$$D u(x',0) = f(x')  $$

Comment: In the book, it also says that $osc_{|x'| < R} Du(x',0) \leq CR^{\alpha}$, that means $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n}$ is not 0

Comment: you said on $T$ $Du = 0$, right? The set I quoted is also $T = \{x\in R^n| |x'| < R, x_n =0\}$.